# Юнит-тестирование методов с вещественными переменными

Tags: c#, юнит-тесты

Метод возвращает вещественное число (при 10 возвращает 314.1593). Как правильно написать юнит-тест?
Я предположил, что нужно создать две переменные `expected1=314` и `expected2=315` и сравнить чтобы результат лежал в пределах. Но как-то это криво. Есть специальный способ для этого?

Comment: "при 10 возвращает 314.1593" - уточните, что вы тут имеете ввиду?

Comment: Какую именно библиотеку для юнит-тестирования используете? В разных могут использоваться разные методы.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Assert.AreEqual(double expected,double actual,double delta)
```